# MarkLogic 10: Executing Xquery script using /v1/eval endpoint

Tags: marklogic

I have a use case where small xquery modules must be executed via the /v1/eval endpoint.

I need this executed on the `data-hub-FINAL` database which is connected to the appserver on port 8011. My module is stored on the `data-hub-MODULES` database connected to the FINAL database as well. The URI for the xquery module in the MODULES database is `/test/my-script.xqy`.

Give then following curl command, I am unable to get this working with a "No query to eval" error.

`curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST -i -d @./test/my-script.xqy \ -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \ -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" \ http://localhost:8011/v1/eval`

I have followed the MarkLogic documentation here: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval

Is there any insight in what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The /v1/eval is a way to send over code to be evaluated and executed. If you are attempting to invoke an installed module at `/test/my-script.xqy` in the modules database, then look at https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/invoke

Answer (score 0):

The body that you POST needs to be x-www-form-urlencoded, e.g. in the shape of param1=value1&param2=value2. Instead of using the -d argument, you should be able to use the -F argument to get what you want:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST -i -F xquery=@./test/my-script.xqy \
  -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" \
  http://localhost:8011/v1/eval
```

Haven't actually tested, but fairly sure this is the issue.

HTH!